# How many database tables should we have for one project would be proper? would 10,000 be too many?

Tags: database

I see some project has hundreds tables, but some only around one hundred or so. So my questions how many tables would be too many for one project?

For example, would 10,000 be too big?

Comment: That would depend entirely on the project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it depends on project. You can use 0 or 1 or N tables.

Comment: I work with IT for many years. I never saw a company that uses more than 100 tables for 1 project.  I already saw databases with 1000 tables, but they are used in many different projects.

Comment: You can use 10,000 tables. But it not seems to be a general project.

Comment: I don't know your project but the in most of cases a table is created to represent just one object type. If you have 10,000 users for example,  they should be stored in the same table  but their addresses could be stored in another one, for example.

Comment: So mostly it should be around 100 or so?